# VSTS keeps generating new personal access tokens

Tags: azure-devops

Recently I've been getting an email almost exactly every 20 minutes so with the subject "Visual Studio Team Services personal access token added". The content is something like this:

```
A new personal access token was added to your account
    Git: https://[company account].visualstudio.com/ on [USER]
    Scopes: vso.code_write vso.packaging
    Expiration: 7/4/2019
```

The regularity makes me think it's something automatic doing it, but I don't know what that could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the tokens were being generated by Atlassian SourceTree. I don't know what was happening or why it suddenly started, but closing SourceTree resulted in no new tokens being issued. Reopening SourceTree led to the tokens being issued again.

I upgraded SourceTree and Git for Windows and rebooted my computer, and that seems to have done the trick. I had already rebooted my computer since the issue started without that solving things, but the combination of rebooting and upgrading both Git and SourceTree seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

The auto generated PAT description with the format `Git: https://[account].visualstudio.com/ on [machine]` with the scopes Code (read and write) and Packaging (read) is caused by **cloning VSTS git repo**.

[image]

So please check if someone (or some code execute git clone operation) cloned VSTS git repo(s) on different machnes periodly.

Comment: Are there any logs that can show any more info about the event, such as which IP address the request came from?

Comment: No, there has no such logs. And since git clone operation can be done by many manners (command line, VS, by code etc), the event can not be recorded thoroughly.